# Static Generic Methods, Type Inference causes java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, static-methods, type-inference

Consider these classic Person polymorphic hierarchy...

**super-interface**

```
public interface Person {

    String getName();

    interface Builder<P, B extends Builder<P, B>> {
        B name(String name);
        P build();
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student implements Person {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        ...
    }

    public static class Builder implements Person.Builder<Student, Builder> {

        @Override
        public Builder name(String name) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public Student build() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Employee.java**
*I omitted the Employee type here, as its just the same with student*

**PersonBuilderFactory.java**

```
public class PersonBuilderFactory {

public static <T extends Person.Builder> T getBuilder(T...args) {

    if (args.getClass().getComponentType().isAssignableFrom(Student.Builder.class)) {
        return (T) new Student.Builder();
    } else if (args.getClass().getComponentType().isAssignableFrom(Employee.Builder.class)) {
        return (T) new Employee.Builder();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("No such builder for other person types");
}
```

**TestInference.java**

```
public class TestInference {

public static void testInference() {

    Compile Test 1
    // java wants me to infer the type argument
    // which will build perfectly fine
    Student.Builder studentBuilder1 = PersonBuilderFactory.<Student.Builder>getBuilder();
    Employee.Builder employeeBuilder1 = PersonBuilderFactory.<Employee.Builder>getBuilder();

    Compile Test 2
    // so if i remove those explicit type arguments
    // everything still works fine
    Student.Builder studentBuilder2 = PersonBuilderFactory.getBuilder(); // this will implicitly  get a student builder
    Employee.Builder employeeBuilder2 = PersonBuilderFactory.getBuilder(); // this will have an employee builder

    Compile Test 3
    // Now...
    // leaving the argument type NOT inferred and changing the data type
    // gives me a compile error which is Im expecting and I want
    String someString = PersonBuilderFactory.<Student.Builder>getBuilder();

    Compile Test 4
    // but when i remove the explicit type argument
    // it compiles but this will cause me a specific Verify Error
    String someAnotherString = PersonBuilderFactory.getBuilder();
}
```

}

Compile Test **1** has explicit type arguments which java is asking me to remove (telling me it is somehow redudant) resulting to compile Test **2**, which works fine

Compile Test **3** is what Im expecting if

- I declared an explicit type argument which is not within the bounds of the declared type of the variable

Compile Test **4** baffles me, why didnt the compiler said anything that it is returning something without the bounds of the Person.Builder (**T** extends Person.Builder), and when I ran the code, it throws me a Verify Error that tells me I have a bad method, my question is why the compiler didnt? but when I explicitly specified a type argument it does, and when Im declaring a correct variable data type, it returns a correct type.

Im totally having a hard time understanding Type Inference here, there are issues that says it has something to do with Java Compiler Version, and another post says "you just have a very complex method"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I ran the code, it throws me a Verify Error that tells me I have a bad method, my question is why the compiler didnt?

Because the compiler can't be sure that you've done something wrong.

The thing is that `Builder` is an interface; notice that if you make `Builder` into a class, the code doesn't compile at all. Type inference doesn't treat `String` in a special way with respect to the fact that it's a final class ([Chapter 18 of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) only mentions "final" in the word "finally"; it does not mention `final` at all).

So it allows case 4 because a class like:

```
class Something extends String implements Person.Builder {}
```

is *possible*, as far as type inference is concerned. Similarly, `<T extends String>` is allowed, even though nothing extends `String`.

The inferred type on that line is the intersection type:

```
INT#1 extends String,Builder
```

(I got this by compiling with `-Xlint:unchecked`'; conveniently, there is a warning about the unchecked generic array creation there)

and hence it seems to be allowed by the compiler.

But then, in the method, the value of `args.getClass().getComponentType()` is `java.lang.String`; this isn't matched by any of your conditions, so it hits the exception at the bottom.

Comment: yes!! thanks so much for reminding me on basics, i forgot the is-a relationship difference between interface and classes(absctract or concrete) that any class can implement MANY interface, but a class can only extend ONE parent class!

Comment: I just dont understand the intersection type :p

Comment: now im getting the desired compile time error i want! :) , "Type Paramter T has incompatible upper bounds"